# How to remove content-length header from http GET request in Flutter?

Tags: rest, flutter, http, header, dio

I try to create a Flutter client app that communicates to REST API.
When I create an HTTP GET request as below, it always includes `content-length:0` and the server returns `status code 400:Bad request`.
If I send a request without this header by another tool, server returns `status code 200:OK`.

```
//import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
final client = http.Client();
final response = await client.get(url);
```

or

```
//import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
final options = BaseOptions();
options.headers.remove(Headers.contentTypeHeader);
options.headers.remove(Headers.contentLengthHeader);
final dio = Dio(options);
final response = await dio.get(url);
```

How can I remove this header?

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have find something ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a backend issue like mine. For my case, my backend developer expected a `body` in the **GET** request but I thought that the **GET** request has no body but finally, We aligned and when I put body in my **GET** request, it was working nice

Comment: If your backend developer expects a body with GET, you should find a different backend developer.